# Redirect root and all requests not starting with a specific dir to another directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I need to write an .htaccess so I end up

- redirecting all requests to `/` to `/2015`
- leave alone all requests to `/2015`
- redirect all requests not starting with `/2015` to `/2014`
- and logically, leave alone all requests going to `/2014`

My feeble attempts ended up like this, but it's obviously not working...

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/2015 [AND]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/2014
RedirectMatch 301 /(.*) /2014/$1

# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?loc.domain$
# RewriteRule ^(/)?$ 2015 [L]
RewriteRule ^$ /2015 [L]
```

**EDIT**
I probably wasn't thorough enough. I need people trying to access
`/anything` to be redirected to `/2014/anything` as well, not to be redirected to the root of `/2014`

Comment: BTW for learning purposes you are mixing mod_alias with mod_rewrite. You can't use `RewriteCond` with `RedirectMatch` you need to use `RewriteRule`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to do it this way.

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ /2015 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^((?!2014|2015).+) /2014/$1 [R=301,L]
```

You also need exclude 2015 and 2014 in the rule or it will end up in a redirect loop.

BTW for learning purposes you are mixing mod_alias with mod_rewrite. You can't use `RewriteCond` with `RedirectMatch` you need to use `RewriteRule`.

Comment: Works, but as I explain in my edit, I also need that when people go to /somepath, they end up on /2014/endpath (after a 301 redirect).

Comment: Ok I updated the answer. Let me know how that works. Clear your browser cache just in case it cached last rule you tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?$ /2015 [L,R]

RewriteRule !^2015 /2014 [L,R]
```